# Js canvas fillRect() coordinates as variable not working

Tags: javascript, canvas

I have a canvas square like this: `draw.fillRect(sq);`
and before that: `sq = "400, 400, 0, 0";`. The console says

"Not enough arguments to CanvasRenderingContext2D.fillRect.".

I assume this is because It treats `sq` as one argument. Is there any way to avoid this? To get all four arguments stored in one variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, your `sq` is a single string and because of that treated as a single variable. Instead try to use an Array like:

```
var sq = [400, 400, 0, 0];
```

And then

```
draw.fillRect.apply(draw, sq);
```

`apply` calls your function with the arguments provided in `sq`. For further 
information take a look at the [Documentation for Function.prototype.apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) at MDN.

---

**NOTE:** You are trying to draw a rectangle at `x = y = 400` with `width = heigth = 0`. So you wont see very much as the size of your rectangle is 0. So you may want to change your params. Take a look at the [documentation of the .fillRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect) method.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption is right, "fillRect" needs 4 arguments.

Here a proposal on how to save them in one variable:

```
Var rectData = {
"x": 400,
"y": 400,
"width": 0,
"height": 0
};
```

And than use it like that:

```
draw.fillRect(rectData.x,rectData.y, rectData.width, rectData.height);
```

By the way: Using a width / height of 0 probably is not what you want. You will not see any rectangle :) Best test your code-snippets first, e.g. in the
[Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/fillRect).

Compared to the 'apply' solution, using a object literal will make your code more readable so debugging will be simpler.

Comment: Fixed. I quess MDN for JS did not exist the time I was programming JS.  Although I have to say I dont like the implications the name of the url 'w3fools' does. It should be sufficient to say that MDN is the better choice on the long run, since w3schools is made for beginners.

Comment: I agree with you. I guess W3School became better over the last years (as did MDN). Anyway one should always check several sources :)