# Using JavaScript Math. methods as HTML Canvas .fillRect Co-ordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

hope you're all well!

I've spent the entire evening trying to figure out how to use `(Math.floor(Math.random())` as the co-ordinates for the `.fillRect` method used on the HTML canvas element.

I've looked around this site and online for some answer, but nothing suggested has worked so far. My current approach is based on [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36738005/js-canvas-fillrect-coordinates-as-variable-not-working).

I want to draw a 20*20px rectangle at a random point on the canvas every time I click a button. I have everything working except feeding the randomised numbers I get from the `Math` methods into the `.fillRect` co-ordinate arguments.

This is my HTML code and my JS code:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

$("#btn").click(function() {

  var rectCoord = {
    "x": (Math.floor(Math.random() * 699) + 1), //Canvas is 700px wide.
    "y": (Math.floor(Math.random() * 599) + 1), //Canvas is 600px high.
  };


  console.log(rectCoord.x, rectCoord.y)
  //Test. Random X and Y points log in console correctly.

  ctx.fillRect(rectCoord.x, rectCoord.y, 20, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
  <button id="btn">Click!</button>

</div>
```

The `console.log` was where I was testing if:

1) The "x" and "y" points were being randomised on every click, and

2) The rectCoord.x, rectCoord.y data-points were coming through properly to be used in a following line of code.

The randomised points are logging to console fine, and whenever I just put in integers for the co-ordinate arguments in `fillRect` it draws a rectangle perfectly.

I just can't figure out how to insert the randomised points as arguments in `.fillRect`. Why are they working as arguments for `console.log`and not for `.fillRect`?

Thank you very much in advance for any replies, I'm pretty new to coding and I just can't wrap my head around this!! Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting `ctx.fillStyle = 'black'` or something like that?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't make a difference.

 `fillStyle` is black by default anyhow, and when I put in numbers (eg. 40, 500) for the co-ordinate arguments the code runs as it should. That's why I think it has something to do with me trying to use a changing variable as the co-ordinate value. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: You should use `ctx.fillRect((Math.random()*ctx.canvas.width-20) | 0,(Math.random() * ctx.canvas.height -20) | 0, 20, 20);` to ensure a 20 by 20 rectangle **Always** appears on the canvas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*you have to put the canvas size (maybe you have it in the stylesheet)*

and then simply delete the old position and update it

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//creates a function for the random value
function rectCoord(){
  return {
    "x": (Math.floor(Math.random()*699)+1),
    "y": (Math.floor(Math.random()*599)+1)
  }
}
//defines the initial values
var x = 0,//rectCoord().x
    y = 0;//rectCoord().y
//then draw
ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
$("#btn").click(function() {
  //in each click delete the previous state
  ctx.clearRect(x, y, 20, 20);
  //renews values
  x = rectCoord().x;
  y = rectCoord().y;
  //renews the position of the drawing
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 20, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">
  <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="600"></canvas>
  <button id="btn">Click!</button>
</div>
```

Comment: The only important thing to take away from this is setting the canvas size. Changing only that causes the squares to always draw. If you click the button in the question demo enough times, a square will _eventually_ render, but the chance is fairly low that it falls within the default bounds of a canvas.

Comment: Aha! Thank you very much!! So I added width and height attributes to the canvas tag, and this instantly fixes the problem. However I already had these values in the css stylesheet. What is the difference between the in-line attribute and declaring in an external stylesheet? @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @Pete CSS stylesheet causes the canvas "pixels" to "stretch" in order to fit the CSS dimensions onscreen, whereas the attributes control how many pixels are actually contained in the canvas image data. This behavior is due to `<canvas>` using [CSS `object-fit: fill;` rule](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/object-fit/) by default.

Answer (score 0):

The rectangle you draw is out of the canvas range, set the width and height at `<canvas>` tag:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="600"></canvas>
```

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var width = canvas.width;
var height = canvas.height;

$("#btn").click(function() {

  var rectCoord = {
    "x": (Math.floor(Math.random() * width) + 1),
    "y": (Math.floor(Math.random() * height) + 1)
  };


  console.log(rectCoord.x, rectCoord.y)
  //Test. Random X and Y points log in console correctly.

  ctx.fillRect(rectCoord.x, rectCoord.y, 20, 20);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="container">

  <button id="btn">Click!</button>
  <canvas id="canvas" width="700" height="600"></canvas>

</div>
```